# Does Google BigQuery support other than date partition?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am novice to BigQuery. I am looking for an option to partition a table by a String field like City/Country or a Date field like Start_Date?

Appreciate response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, currently it is only possible to partition by date. You can track the status of [this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905817) to be able to partition by other columns.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#partitioned_tables